# Is there a way to convert image with R ? JPEG to GIF for example

Tags: image, r, gif

I wish to display images in a tcltk window (not in a R device) using R but the simpliest method (below) supports only GIF files :

```
require(tcltk)
tcl("image","create","photo", "imageID", file="a.gif")
w <- tktoplevel()
l <- ttklabel(w, image="imageID", compound="image")
tkpack(l)
```

and I my files are png/jpeg (file containing histograms generated by my program itself)

someone has an idea to do that conversion ?

thank you

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ImageMagick to convert the file formats very easily.

Comment: Yes..but I want it to be automatic.

Comment: @user2551551 - you could call imagemagick from inside R using a `system()` call and then continue on your merry way.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed? You can "automatically" call imageMagick commands from inside of R by using the `system` function. For example, if I want to call the system command `ls` in R, I can use `system('ls')` (or maybe if you're on Windows, you can try it using `system('dir')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the warnings this seems to succeed:

```
 png("test.png")
 plot(1,1)
 dev.off()
#quartz 
 #    2 
 library(png)
 help(package="png")
 img <- readPNG("test.png")
 str(img)
# num [1:480, 1:480, 1:4] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 require(caTools)
#Loading required package: caTools
 write.gif(img, "test.gif", scale="always")
#-----------------
Warning message:
In if (col == "jet") col = colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: OK.. it works. but gif is animated, and has no color. but it works.